# Designing endpoints for multiple filters

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, oop, design-patterns

I am curious if there is a better way to handle an advanced filter design. I have an API for a music catalog that allows users to search for tracks based on the following criteria (if nothing is provided then it just returns a paginated result of all tracks ordered by added date)

that means a base endpoint of something like http://www.myapi.com/api/tracks
Then I offer the following parameters to allow for advanced filtering based on multiple things if they choose to do so. If a parameter is not provided then it is not included in the query at all.

Artist Name / Song Title

Genre(s)

Key(s)

BPM Range

Version Type(s)

For example, you could search for Rock songs that are in key 2A, and all songs that meet that criteria would be returned. The endpoint would then look something like this:

http://www.myapi.com/api/tracks?genres=ROCK&keys=2A

My question is that in designing something like this is there any other approach than setting up your endpoint to basically brute force through all of the possible request param combinations and having a separate query for basically each combo?

When I think of this I think of something like Linkedin's advanced filter ... surely they can't brute force that kind of thing, it would be terrible to maintain and scale. How is that kind of functionality usually implemented in production systems?

Comment: URL query parameters are dynamic by nature, and you can pass almost anything through them. The only endpoint you need is `.../api/tracks` that would have some mappings between URL query parameters and string variables you can pass to data repository. No need "brute force" at all (that "brute force" would fail at simple `http://www.myapi.com/api/tracks?genres=ROCK&keys=2A` and `http://www.myapi.com/api/tracks?keys=2A&genres=ROCK` right?).

Comment: @fluffy not exactly. I understand the part about the request parameters being dynamic. I was more so getting at once you receive the request and then you want to pass them on to the data repository. Like let's say for example I pass through through the example above, it does not matter the order the parameters that are passed through but if I were to modify it to include an additional param for search for the artist/song title, that would require a different query for the data repo but with 5 filters and multiple combos of params that could be included, that means many queries in the data repo

Comment: You could just dynamically construct the query based on what param(s) are passed. Of course, a massive site like LinkedIn would solve this problem very differently than a small API backed by an RDBMS.

Comment: @fluffy I would essentially need a data repo query for if key/genre is included and then one for if search/key/genre ... then one for bpmRange/genre and then one for search/bpmRange/genre etc. I was just thinking this can't be how it is implemented in production systems.

Comment: @oznomal I'm confused, so your main concern is not about URL query parameters, but more of generating a dynamic filter query to the underlying data source?

Comment: @fluffy yes, I don't think that I was looking at it like that since I was using spring data and I mainly depending on some of the out of the box implementations for the repository layer, But I guess what I need to be doing is dynamically creating the query ... I don't know why I didn't think of that. I was sitting there trying to generate every combo possible. But I guess I could just create a base query and then append parts to it if that request param was included. I just will need to find out how to pass that to my repositry layer in spring data which I am sure is possible.

Comment: @oznomal If you're using Java and Spring Boot, I'm assuming you're using JPA, therefore something like `CriteriaBuilder` is the very first that comes to mind. I use it in the system I maintain and develop, and it allows constructing queries dynamically, so that one can easily implement mapping between query parameters and the criteria builder methods. In general, it allows creating a base query (essentially, which table to use), and then it can be grown up by adding new filters programmatically. (UPD: Just like you described in your last sentences.)

Comment: The best way to create dynamic queries for dynamic filter is to use Java JPA Criteria API.
You can construct dynamic JPA query using Java JPA Criteria API.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you simply append "AND FieldName1 = ?" to the SQL query for every specified parameter? (and passing the actual value as a parameter so it's not vulnerable to SQL injection). If you need JOINS simply keep the SQL query string in three different string variables and concatenate them once all parameters (and join) have been done.